# How should I create I/O types (e.g. File) at runtime when using Dependency Injection

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection

Even with DI, our business/service types need to create some transitive objects in their methods. These transitive objects I would say are always either value types (representing pure data) or I/O types (representing external state). Value types are OK to new up, but I/O types we want to mock/stub in testing, so we can't create them directly.

The common solution I see is to give the class some kind of IOFactory dependency: in production, we provide a factory to the class that makes real I/O objects; in tests, we provide a factory to the class that makes fake I/O objects.

What I don't like about this is the obligation to create not just mock/stub I/O types but also factories for both the real type and its substitutes. This feels burdensome, especially in dynamic languages like JS where I can often easily create my mocks/stubs ad hoc for each test.

The alternative that occurs to me is to use an injector sort of like a service locator...

```
var file = injector.inject(File, '/path');  // given type, returns new instance of that type
```

...such that, in production, the injector is configured to provide a real file, whereas in test, it is configured to return a mock/stub instead. We could just treat the injector as a special global, but arguably the injector is now a dependency of every business type that needs to use it, and so it should be injected like any other dependency.

The main argument I see in favor of this idea is that the injector in many cases can reduce factory boilerplate (at the cost of some extra factory configuration work). What are the arguments against? Are factories better because they're more specific declarations of what the class needs and thus serve as documentation? Or is the proper solution totally different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On using an `injector` as a [Service Locator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern):

The Service Locator is sometimes described as [being an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) because:

- Using it incorrectly leads to code that is hard to maintain
- It is *very easy* to use *incorrectly*

(Some developers [raise objections](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/467720/Service-locator-is-not-an-anti-pattern) about calling it an anti-pattern, but still generally agree that it has a specific purpose and is often misused.)

The `injector` that you describe is a prime example of the anti-pattern. With it, your object would now have a hidden **required** dependency - one that is not declared in its constructor.

If the injector is not configured by the time the object uses it, a run-time error will occur. It is possible that someone may not realize that this configuration is needed in order for the object to function properly (*you* might even be that someone, 6 months from now).

The idea behind dependency injection is that an object is very explicit about what it needs in order to behave as expected. The rationale behind this is the same as that used for the interface maxim: [Easy to use correctly; Hard to use incorrectly](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Make_Interfaces_Easy_to_Use_Correctly_and_Hard_to_Use_Incorrectly).

You're right that it can sometimes be cumbersome having to introduce factories to be able to dynamically instantiate objects - but a lot of that boilerplate is often rooted in the verbose syntax of many OO languages; not necessarily in the concept of dependency injection.

So, it's ok to use the Service Locator approach for short-term convenience (just like any other global variable) - as long as you realize that *that* is all it really offers in situations like this.

---

As for alternatives, don't forget that required dependencies don't necessarily need to be passed as constructor arguments.

Instead of passing a factory into the constructor of an class, it sometimes make sense to use the [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) approach. That is, force derived classes to provide the dependency instead of expecting it to come from the creator of the object.

If the SUT can be initialized with a meaningful default dependency (e.g., a [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)), you can consider injecting the dependency in a setter method.

In C/C++, developers sometimes even rely on the *linker* to handle dependency injection. In his book, [Test-Driven Development for Embedded C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193435662X), James Grenning writes:

> To break the dependencies on the production code, think of the collaborators only in terms of their interfaces. [...] The interface is represented by the header file, and the implementation is represented by the source file. `LightScheduler` [the SUT] is bound to the production code implementation at link time.
>
> The unit tests take advantage of the link seam by providing alternative implementations. (p.120)

In the end, ask what you're hoping to get from dependency injection. If the benefits don't outweigh the work involved in implementing it, then maybe it's unnecessary. But don't eschew it just to save a little bit of time in the short-term.

Comment: Thanks. I think I found the answer: better for classes to give as specific information as possible about their dependencies. Abstract Factories aren't totally specific, but they're much more specific than an Injector. This may not matter for code that stays within a single program written by one or two people, but using the injector as a service locator (even if just for i/o types) would be terrible for any external consumers of the classes.

Comment: You're right this is a language problem: what I really want is a convenient, concise way to create boilerplate abstract factories.